Issues installing libgl1-mesa-glx
I'm trying to install libgl1-mesa-glx since I need it to run packettracer.
fabio@fabio-MS-7750:~/packettracer$ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgl1-mesa-glx' has no installation candidate

I'm aware there are duplicates of this issue but they are 10 years old and the error message makes me believe it has to do with obsolescence of the package
Running on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS

Please add your ubuntu version via [edit]{https://askubuntu.com/posts/1517352/edit) to your question.

As far as I can tell, Cisco only offers Packet Tracer for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and  22.04 LTS so far. Starting with Ubuntu 23.10, there are unmet dependencies as you found out. There is a note about installing Packet Tracer on Ubuntu 23.10, that you maybe can adapt to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. You'll probably need to go look for libegl1-mesa and libgl1-mesa-glx packages for Ubuntu 24.04 LTS instead of those geared for Ubuntu 23.10.

libgl1-mesa-glx has been a transitional package for a while and is now obsolete from Ubuntu 23.10 and onwards.
Installing libgl1 and libglx-mesa0 instead of libgl1-mesa-glx will result in equivalent behaviour and should work on Ubuntu 18.04 and newer.

this solve my problem in Ubuntu 24.04LTS
libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1.22.04.1_amd64.deb DOWNLOAD
https://github.com/PetrusNoleto/Error-in-install-cisco-packet-tracer-in-ubuntu-23.10-unmet-dependencies/releases/tag/CiscoPacketTracerFixUnmetDependenciesUbuntu23.10
exec :
sudo dpkg -i libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1.22.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libgl1-mesa-glx_23.0.4-0ubuntu1.22.04.1_amd64.deb

Screenshot

This worked for me
